# WP8.1 - Loading Https Uri's to UI Components ignoring the SSL certificate

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a requirement where I need to ignore SSL cerificate(Https) and get the Videos and Photos data from our Network attached Device which has got Invalid SSL Certificate.

I used HttpClient to Ignore SSL certificate and got the data, but when I load the Thumbnail Url's and Video Url's to BitmapImage and VideoPlayer respectively, the BitmapImage is not loaded to Image and Video Player fails to play the video.

Please let me know is there any way to achieve this, If yes please help me to understand.

PS: The project is Windows Universal 8.1

Comment: Can you switch to HTTP when the cert is invalid?

Comment: If it is a self-signed certificate, you may get it with HttpCleint and add it to `CertificateStores.TrustedRootCertificationAuthorities`

Comment: WiredPrairie, No I can't switch to HTTP

Comment: Hi Kiewic Thanks
But my problem is something else. I have service where they are ignoring the SSL and giving the feeds to me. But the https URL's are not ignored by the UI components i.e Image and Video Player. So Is there any way to do it globally for the app to ignore SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ignoring the server certificate errors, I recommend you including the self-singed Certificates in your app.

Blog: [Including Self-Signed Certificates with your Windows Runtime based Windows Phone 8.1 apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/06/05/including-self-signed-certificates-with-your-windows-runtime-based-windows-phone-8-1-apps.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jeffrey 
This is not going to solve my problem because the SSL certificate will be installed in the Network Device from which I fetch the data. It can either have valid certificate or invalid certificate. If its valid I cant add the certificate(Self Signed) again, if its not valid may be I can do the way you are suggesting. I think Ignoring Certificate is the better option If its not valid. Is there any way?